# Making barplot axis more readable: how to place ticks at some positions on the X axis so they correspond to specific bars for a large vector

Tags: r, plot

Say i have a fairly long vector which i want to present as a barplot:

```
myvec<-runif(2000,0,1)
barplot(myvec, col="grey", border=NA, names.arg  = seq(1:2000))
```

[image]

i would like x axis to go pretty:
to have, say 4-5 labels to be shown on the axis, but with the ticks that determine to which specific bar it corresponds.
worst to worst i can live with the random labels that are being picked automatically, but i want to see which bar they correspond to.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)

myvec<-data.frame(v1=runif(2000,0,1))

ggplot(myvec,aes(x=dplyr::row_number(v1),y=v1))+geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i want the original order to be preserved. here you are sorting your vector. i was able to get the ticks though :)